# Home button listener in background

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, clicklistener

I want to create service (?), which would be running in the background all the time and start when system starts. Also, I want it to detect double home button press and then launch a specified activity. Is it possible?

Comment: You can not catch the Home button event for safety reasons (gods of Android don't want developers to create applications that the user can not exit).

Answer (score 2):

**1.** When system starts you can do like this:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Intent launch = new Intent(context, ServiceToLaunch.class);
            launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(launch);
        }
    }
}
```

In your manifest add this:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Add permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**2.** There is no Home key event available.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. So, if I cannot detect home button press, is it possible to detect, when user slides his finger from the bottom to the top of the screen?